# Commands for changing screen Brightness

Tags: brightness, 22.04, xrandr

Goal: In/decrease screen brightness (by *"standard"* in/decrements) via. **one-liner commands**.

Following this [tutorial](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/how-to-change-screen-brightness-in-ubuntu-using-command-terminal.html), no change occurred:

```
(base) moi@ubuntu-pcs:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for moi: 
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [109 kB]     
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Get:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]  
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [11.4 kB]
Get:7 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [73.4 kB]
Get:8 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [91.8 kB]
Get:9 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1,196 B]
Fetched 497 kB in 2s (272 kB/s)               
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
125 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
N: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages', as repository 'https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
(base) moi@ubuntu-pcs:~$ xrandr | grep " connected" | cut -f1 -d " "
XWAYLAND0
(base) moi@ubuntu-pcs:~$ xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --brightness 0.5
```

---

`lsb_release -a`:

```
(base) moi@ubuntu-pcs:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the utility `light`: `sudo apt install light`. Following example commands decrease and increase the brightness:

```
light -U 10    
light -A 10
```

`light` modifies brightness at the level of the hardware. It runs with elevated permissions. An udev rule is automatically installed, but I could not get `light` to work after adding my user to the `video` group. The alternative, less secure, is to set the `suid` bit:

```
sudo chmod +s $(which light)
```

`xrandr` cannot work on a default Ubuntu 22.04 install because that is using Wayland rather than Xorg.

Comment: I installed it but the commands make no difference ;( I have my brightness at exactly 50% to easily check for changes

Comment: Try larger numbers: these small changes are not seen when your screen is already at 50%. I increased the values in the examples to make it more obvious for those who try.

Comment: Still no changes ;(

Comment: What should I replace `USER` with in `sudo usermod -a -G video $USER`?

Comment: I printed `whoami` and pasted that after the `sudo usermod -a -G video $`<blah>.

Comment: I also could not get it to work with the udev rule, i.e., adding myself to 'video'. Perhaps `video` is not properly set up in Ubuntu anymore? A more "classical" and less safe method is to suid the executable. I updated the question on how to do that instead.

Comment: Working now! Thank you :)