there is no brightness adjustment
How do I get the brightness adjustment to the upper right corner. It wasn't there at all. I am using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. Netflix, YouTube and all other videos are so dark that the old TV doesn't show dark spots. With the Vlc player, I can adjust the movies a little so that I can see the differences, but the others are dark and can't be seen. A little help like that would help.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413987/commands-for-changing-screen-brightness

See at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1530943/i-cant-adjust-the-brightness-in-ubuntu-24-10

Please add more details about your hardware. Is this a laptop or a desktop?

Your problem is not with Ubuntu itself:
As far as I am aware, TVs can not control their brightness by emitting less/more light, unlike monitors; Because of this the option to control the brightness becomes obsolete, hence the reason why you can't control the brightness.
The best solution would be to use a monitor, but if that's not feasible you could try using the gnome shell extension ColorTint to apply a screen-wide white filter and kinda brighten the content.
If you are not familiar with gnome extensions, you can follow this guide to learn more or go straight here to install them.
